# Angular UI Bootstrap Datepicker - show specific date on Calendar open

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

I am using [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) dirrective for Datepicker. I have list of dates, that I set in calendar as active (i.e. other dates are disabled).

Here is my date list - `["10/16/2015", "11/20/2015", "12/18/2015"]`

UI Datepicker always open current date/month. How can I make, so calendar would open on specific date, even if this date is from previous year?

I found option [defaultViewDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id3) option, but it seems that it doesn't work (at least I didn't find this method in tpl library)

Any ideas how I can make that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given Angular UI's [documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) on its datepicker, the calendar adapts to a date set on the **ng-model**, so all you'd have to do is create a date:

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

See [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for more on that.

Set the model to that and you should be good to go. Let us know if it works.

**EDIT:**

To set the initial date when no date is specified, use **init-date** by creating a default date on the *scope* of the parent controller.

```
angular.module("yourModule").controller("parentCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.initialDate = new Date(2000, 5, 4);
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="parentCtrl">
    <datepicker init-date="initialDate"></datepicker>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You right, I can set ng-model (called $scope.dt here), and actually I already made seting first date from my list when DatepickerPopup is open, but problem is - how can I open Datepicker Popup first time and first month, that I will see - will be some month from the past without seting ng-model, just have a chance to select from past dates

Comment: Their datepicker can take an "init-date" attribute, which is **"the initial date view when no model value is specified."**

Comment: Yes, i tried it, but it seems that it doesn't work. Or, I use it wrong. Here is plunker link with example from UI site - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLEkDnq4PqpaWhpgtHQu?p=preview

Comment: Add the inital date on the parent scope and pass it as a parameter to **init-date**, like so: 
`$scope.initDate = new Date(1984, 10, 5);`
And in HTML:
`init-date="initDate"`

Comment: Looks like it works :) I just noticed, that I have used old version in my project, and found on github, that this issue was fixed in new version. Thank you very much!